# How do you change a fixed position h2's colour as you scroll down the page?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

On my [website](http://patrickaltair.com/paris.html) I have a little sidebar of h2's that help you navigate. This works fine on the homepage but not on the pages where the photos don't fill the entire screen. When you scroll down the white text on a white background makes the text impossible to read. Is there a way so that when you scroll past the div (35% of the page) the text can change colour from white to black?

This guy [here](http://lorenzoverzini.com/) seems to do something similar with a svg of his logo if that helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [jQuery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) before to good effect. It's pretty simple to use, you specify the points at which things are executed, and when it scrolls to there it does them. I've used a similar effect to the one you're describing [here](http://ksiolajidebt.com/).

Comment: Looks like this might work but I've got some learning to do haha. Thanks

Comment: It's not too tricky at all. The documentation is a bit rubbish, so if you get stuck give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JS Fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/uMPuW/39/

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
       var $scrollingDiv = $("#hdr");

       $(window).scroll(function () {
           $scrollingDiv.stop()
               .animate({
               "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"
           }, "slow");
           $scrollingDiv.css("color", (($(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height()) > 0.35) ? "orange" : "");
       });
   });
```

Comment: This looks like it might work. I'm not familiar with JS though. Is there a way to change the text colour instead of the background color? Also is it possible to get rid of the lag on the scroll? Ideally I'd like it to stay in a fixed position all the time. Thanks for your help

Comment: hii..i have updated the fiddle again..can u have a look...??I hope this is what you want

Comment: Hi arun, sorry I didn't reply. No the solution didn't work for me as the text seems to lag behind as you scroll. I would like it to stay in a fixed position all the time.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle..it lagged cause of position:absolute..i have changed to position:fixed..